# How can I install Ubuntu 13.04 inside Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

How do I go about installing Ubuntu 13.04 inside Ubuntu 12.04 LTS? I need the LTS for stability (work) but want to experiment a little?

Comment: You mean virtualization? Then use VirtualBox (https://www.virtualbox.org/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to experiment with 13.04, you can do a few things:

1. Probably closest to your specified goal - you can use VirtualBox to [create a Virtual Ubuntu 13.04 machine](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox). (I know the link says Windows, but the instructions are the same). You can install VirtualBox from the Software Center.
2. Use a [Live USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) with persistence enabled. That way, you can experiment without changing your current setup at all.
3. You can install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Ubuntu 12.04. If you wind up choosing to delete the new OS, you will have to remove the new partition and resize the old one with GParted and then use [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to restore the boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

For experimental purposes, you can try Ubuntu live on a USB stick or install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and create a virtual machine.

Comment: Am reading about VB right now; will go that route!